# Writing JQuery function more efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that works just fine, but I feel like it could be written better.

```
$mainTabs.click(function() {
    $('video')[0].pause();
    $('video')[0].currentTime = 0;
});
```

Can I re-write this so it is on one line instead of two? I tried the code below, but got the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentTime' of undefined". The video still pauses, but doesn't rewind like it should. Am I doing something wrong, or is my first attempt as efficient as it gets? I suppose I could save $('video') in a variable, but was hoping to only have to use that selector once anyway.

```
$mainTabs.click(function() {
    $('video')[0].pause().currentTime = 0;
});
```

Comment: because `pause()` does not return a reference to the video element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only methods that are designed to be chained can be used in a chained fashion: it is the method itself returning "this" or a suitable chained object.

In this case `pause()` is not designed to be chainable and does not return anything (the effect is that the method invocation expression results in the undefined value).

To write it "more efficiently" - mainly as in, less repeat - consider using a local variable.

```
$mainTabs.click(function() {
    var video = $('video')[0];
    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 0;
});
```

---

While there are times when a local variable *may* make a 'performance' difference due to avoiding re-evaluation of expressions, in this case there will be no *practical* performance difference as the evaluation is relatively fast and done very infrequently. Using a local variable does much more for clarity of intent in cases like this.

Comment: not strictly true, you're only calling the `$` function once in your example rather than twice as in the OP, so your code will be more efficient.

Comment: *No* performance *benefit*. The difference 'every click' is irrelevant. While it is very possible to construct cases where it matters, 97/3 .. I urge using local variables for clarity of intent foremost.

Answer (score 1):

As `currentTime()` requires a video object to operate on and `pause()` just changes the state of the video object without returning the object itself you will get the error you describe.

It's not always more efficient to make just one line out of code that can be two or more. Consider how readable it is to other developers.

Comment: > Consider how readable it is to other developers.
YES. This is way more important than saving a line of source code.

Comment: Agree with Adam and Toni about the importance of readability, but I consider this one-liner call chain more readable. However ... (1) that is _completely_ aside from whether or not it's more efficient, and (2) can't do it here for the reason in user2864740's answer anyway.